# Github - Release action not working for 'unpublish' type

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow defined as follows:

```yaml
name: Release
on:
  release:
    types: [published, unpublished]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
// ...
```

This works perfectly when I create a release from the Github UI and the pipeline runs as expected because of the `published` type. However when I delete the release the pipeline/workflow does not trigger whereas it should according to the configured `unpublish` type which is [documented](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release) as:

> unpublished: a release or pre-release is deleted

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried the `deleted` type? I'm not sure when which type is triggered, but there are two separate ones.

Comment: Deleted is the same as unpublished except that it applies to drafts as well, which I do not want.